# Line Chart not working properly

Tags: java, android

I want to do several things with my code

1. I want to see all the Y Axis Label (Here in my code the last Label Not display).
2. I want to set the height the chart I need that it look like landscape (In my code the   chart is so longed).

due to my low reputation I am not able to post image

please help me and sorry for bad English.

thanks in advance.
here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

{
    private View mChart;

```
private String[] mMonth = new String[]  {
                                            "Jan", "Feb" , "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                                            "Jul", "Aug" , "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
                                        };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    openChart();
}

  private void openChart()
  {

      int[] x ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
      int[] income ={20, 25, 27, 30, 28, 35, 37, 38};
      int[] expense ={22, 27, 29, 28, 26, 30, 33, 34};

      //Creating an  XYSeries for Income
      XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Income");

      // Creating an  XYSeries for Expense
      XYSeries expenseSeries = new XYSeries("Expense");

      // Adding data to Income and Expense Series
      for(int i=0 ; i<x.length ; i++)
      {
          incomeSeries.add(x[i], income[i]);
          expenseSeries.add(x[i],expense[i]);
      }

      // Creating a dataset to hold each series
      XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

      // Adding Income Series to the dataset
      dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);

      // Adding Expense Series to dataset
      dataset.addSeries(expenseSeries);

      // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
      XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
      incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      incomeRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
      incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
      incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
      incomeRenderer.setChartValuesSpacing(10);
      incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
      incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(15);
      incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);


      // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
      XYSeriesRenderer expenseRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
      expenseRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
      expenseRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
      expenseRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
      expenseRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
      expenseRenderer.setChartValuesSpacing(10);
      expenseRenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
      expenseRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(15);
      expenseRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

      // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
      XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

      // Use To Display The Line In The Middle Of Chart
      multiRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
      multiRenderer.setShowGridY(true);

      // (new int[] {top, left, bottom, right})
      multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {0,60,1,20});
      multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
      multiRenderer.setChartTitle("\n Income vs Expense Chart");
      multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);

      multiRenderer.setYLabels(2);
      multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
      multiRenderer.setYTitle("\nAmount in Dollars");

      multiRenderer.setXTitle("\n\n\n\n Year 2013");
      multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);

      // Visible-InVisible Zoom Button
      multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);

      // Stop Moving Chart
      multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);

      for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
          multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, mMonth[i]);
      } 

      // Adding incomeRenderer and expenseRenderer to multipleRenderer
      // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
      // should be same
      multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
      multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer);

      // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
      LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

      // Creating a Line Chart
      mChart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer);

      // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
      chartContainer.addView(mChart);
  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: can any one plz help me i am not understand whats the problem with my code .